# Shell Linux,работа с портами

Tags: linux, shell

Вообщем,есть файл с портами,и нужно чтоб каждый порт проверялся,и если на порту больше 1 айпи адреса подключено-то выполнял бы действие которое я ему задам.

Comment: nmap пройдитесь по списку. составьте такие списки для каждого ip. потом их можно уже сложить и посчитать

Comment: База постоянно дополняется портами

Comment: Если речь про поле port в IP пакете, то максимум 65к, больше не бывает. А чтобы проверять, лучше решать обратную задачу, то есть выдавать список портов, на которых больше одного адреса. В любом случае это очень легко сделать через netfilter / eBPF.